# Record from the microphone indefinitely

Tags: arch-linux, audio, recording

I'm working with the application "arecord" (under Arch Linux). I'm want to capture sound from my microphone and save it to the disk.

This is my command:

```
arecord -f dat -d 2 --channels 1 -D hw:1,0 /tmp/test.wav
```

This captures a two seconds (`-d` -> duration) file and then saves it to disk. This basically works.

What I want to do is to record an "infinite" sound track (*without* fixed duration) and save this track immediately to disk. Without waiting for it to finish. So, if I shut down the machine while recording (or there's a power outage), the sound track will be saved on the disk up to that moment.

Is this possible?

Comment: How about `arecord -f dat -d 0 --channels 1 -D hw:1,0 > /tmp/test.wav`?

Comment: Can't you just omit the `-d` option? I mean, isn't it the default behaviour of `arecord` to run continuously until killed?

Comment: Yes. For more info: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/arecord1.html

Comment: What if I want to write a MP3 file (instead of WAV) and still write it to disk as it recording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from the [arecord's man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/arecord):

```
-d, --duration=#
          Interrupt after # seconds. A value of zero means infinity. The default is zero, so if this option is omitted then the record/play‐
          back process will run until it is killed.
```

This is the command I used to record sound indefinitely with a [Kinobo Akiro](https://kinobo.co.uk/products/kinobo-akrio-2-usb-condenser-microphone?variant=30344384651) USB microphone using a sampling rate of 48 kHz:

```
arecord --device="hw:1,0" --format=S16_LE --rate=48 rec_$(date "+%F_%H-%M-%S").wav
```

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/597227/linux-arecord-capture-sound-card-output-rather-than-microphone-input#1138439) on how to specify which device to use.

To convert a WAVE file into mp3, you can use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/):

```
ffmpeg -i rec.wav -acodec mp3 rec.mp3
```